# Connection refused Docker, Laravel & MariaDB

Tags: docker, mariadb

I am deploying an application with the following technologies: Laravel + MariaDB + phpMyAdmin.

In the Dockerfile the application image is created and in the docker-compose all the services are orchestrated within a network and through environment variables defined in the .env they are called ports and passwords.

Unfortunately there is something that does not work correctly because you do not have access to the DB, to inspect each container the logs were used but they do not show any errors and when trying to connect remotely to the DB if I have a connection, pinging from one container to another there is also a connection , even within the application container to the database.

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=database
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=mysql
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_ADMIN_PORT=8086
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      target: ${APP_ENV}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    ports:
      - "${APP_PORT}:80"
    volumes:
    - /user/dir:/var/www/html
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - name_network
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    image: mariadb:10.5.6
    container_name: appdb
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - name_network

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "${DB_ADMIN_PORT}:80"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_PORT: ${DB_PORT}
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - name_network

networks:
  networks:
  name_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db_data:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.2.4-apache AS production

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd pdo pdo_mysql

COPY . /var/www/html
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data storage
RUN chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www/html/storage/

RUN composer clear-cache
RUN composer install --no-dev --ignore-platform-req=ext-zip --no-scripts

#RUN php artisan config:cache

EXPOSE 8085
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

**database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'database'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mysql'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

Comment: recommend moving up from 10.5.6 too, there's been almost 3 years of [bug fixes and releases](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes-mariadb-105-series/) since then. `MYSQL_DATABASE` and `MYSQL_USER` are optional things that are created. They will already exist so these don't need to be specified. Why is the 'mysql' system database the default for the app? Looks odd. Anyway, happy MariaDBing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are connecting using port "3307" (the value of env variable `DB_PORT`) but you should connect to port "3306" as that's the port MySQL/MariaDB is listening to WITHIN your container.

OUTSIDE your container, the service is indeed exposed at port 3307 by your

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml
services:
  database:
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:3306"
```

My suggestion for your config:

```
# .env
DB_PORT=3306
EXPOSE_DB_PORT=3307
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml
services:
  database:
    ports:
      - "${EXPOSE_DB_PORT}:3306"
```

and your `database.php` as is

Comment: It worked! I thank you, days without finding the solution.